# Ruby version of Perl Net::CIDR::Lite?

Tags: ruby, perl

I’m updating an old Perl script to Ruby and having a problem with finding a replacement for one Perl library.

In the Perl script we use `Net::CIDR::Lite`, which takes a start and end ip address range and outputs a CIDR string.

This is a Perl example that shows the functionality:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::CIDR::Lite;
$cidrblocks = Net::CIDR::Lite->new;
$cidrblocks->add_range("109.152.0.0-109.152.7.255");

$coveragezone = "";

@cidrlist = $cidrblocks->list();

$cidrcount=0;
    while ( defined $cidrlist[$cidrcount] ) {
            $coveragezone .= "$cidrlist[$cidrcount]";
    }
    continue {
            $cidrcount++;
    }

print "$coveragezone";
```

This script returns a string:

```
=> 109.152.0.0/21
```

Does anyone know of a Ruby lib or gem I could use to duplicate the functionality of the `add_range` call?

```
$cidrblocks = Net::CIDR::Lite->new;
$cidrblocks->add_range("109.152.0.0-109.152.7.255");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a ruby module which does this translation see

http://wejn.org/stuff/cidr.rb.html

have included it in my rails app and it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the built-in  [`IPAddr` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) which also handles CIDR networks, or you use the [ipaddress gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ipaddress) which provides some additional helpers.

A simple example would be:

```
cidrblocks = []
cidrblocks << IPAddr.new("109.152.0.0/21")

included = cidrblocks.find{|net| net.include?("109.152.6.123") }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the [NetAddr](http://netaddr.rubyforge.org/classes/NetAddr.html) gem, in particular its [NetAddr::CIDR](http://netaddr.rubyforge.org/classes/NetAddr/CIDR.html) class.

It's a very rich IPv4/IPv6 gem.

---

Looking through the three modules I know of, Ruby's built-in IPAddr, NetAddr and IPAddress, mentioned by @holgerjust, none of them give us the ability to supply a start IP and end IP and return the resulting network. They all assume a CIDR form of the network, and then work toward testing the individual IPs to see if they fit into the subnet, or using that subnet definition to generate the IPs themselves.

Comment: had a look at this and cant find a way to enter a start and finsh ip address and get the cidr range, any idea how I could do this in ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Can't find a suitable gem?
Do what comes naturally - reimpliment the Perl module in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be entirely relevant to your question, I ported part of CIDR::Lite to Ruby:

https://github.com/noahhaon/cidr-lite-ruby

I found its performance to be far better than the available ruby alternatives at the time for merging very large sets of overlapping CIDRs.

HTH